# OpenGL Rendering Quads at Wrong Position

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, glfw

**Background Info:**

I am using OpenGL and LWJGL 3 to draw some quads onto the screen. I need to know when the mouse is over a quad. When I render the quads to the screen, I use the OpenGL coordinates, ranging from -1 to 1 for both X and Y and with (0,0) at the center of the screen. When I get the mouse position I use

```
glfwSetCursorPosCallback();
```

which gives me the coordinates ranging from 0 to the width or height of the window and with (0,0) at the top left corner (below the title bar). I then take the mouse coordinate and calculate the OpenGL coordinates.

For example if my window size is (800, 600) and my mouse was at (200, 200) I would get (-0.5, 0.33) [since (400, 300) would map to (0, 0) in OpenGL's coordinates].

**So here's my problem:**

OpenGL includes the title bar in its coordinates, where as `glfwSetCursorPosCallback();` does not. This means that if I render a vertex at (-0.5, 0.33) [like in my example] it renders at around (200, ~210).

As you can see, because the two coordinate systems cover different areas, its more difficult to switch between the coordinate systems.

I have searched for ways to exclude the title bar from OpenGL's coordinates, to completely get rid of the title bar and to get the height of the title bar (so I can include it in my calculations and make the correct adjustments). I haven't been able to figure out how to do any of these, so I'm looking for a way to do so, or a different method that will resolve my problem.

**EDIT 1: Adding Code**

@Nicol Bolas informed me that this is not how OpenGL normally works so there must be something causing this in my code. I believe I've provided the parts of my code that would be responsible for my problem:

Here is my Renderer class [I am using the drawQuad() method]

Note: I am not currently using the view, model, or projection matrices in my shaders.

```
public class Renderer {

    private VertexArrayObject vao;
    private VertexBufferObject vbo;
    private ShaderProgram shaderProgram;

    private FloatBuffer vertices;
    private int numVertices;
    private boolean drawing;

    //private Font font;
    //private Font debugFont;


    public void drawQuad(float x, float y, float width, float height, Color c) {
    /* Calculate Vertex positions */
        float x1 = x;
        float y1 = y;
        float x2 = x + width;
        float y2 = y - height;

    /* Calculate color */
        float r = c.getRed();
        float g = c.getGreen();
        float b = c.getBlue();

    /* Put data into buffer */
        vertices.put(x1).put(y1).put(0.0f).put(r).put(g).put(b);
        vertices.put(x1).put(y2).put(0.0f).put(r).put(g).put(b);
        vertices.put(x2).put(y2).put(0.0f).put(r).put(g).put(b);
        vertices.put(x2).put(y1).put(0.0f).put(r).put(g).put(b);

    /* We drawed X vertices */
        numVertices += 4;
    }


    // Initialize renderer
    public void init(){

        // Set up shader programs
        setupShaderProgram();

        // Enable blending (?????)
        glEnable(GL_BLEND);
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    }

    // Clears drawing area
    public void clear() {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    }

    // Begin rendering
    public void begin() {
        if (drawing) throw new IllegalStateException("Renderer is already drawing.");
        drawing = true;
        numVertices = 0;
    }

    // End rendering
    public void end() {
        if (!drawing) throw new IllegalStateException("Renderer is not drawing.");
        drawing = false;
        flush();
    }

    // Flushes data to GPU to get rendered
    public void flush() {
        if (numVertices > 0) {
            vertices.flip();

            if (vao != null) vao.bind();
            else vbo.bind(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
            specifyVertexAttributes();
        }
        shaderProgram.use();

        // Upload the new vertex data
        vbo.bind(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
        vbo.uploadSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, vertices);

        // Draw batch
        glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, numVertices);

        // Clear vertex data for next batch
        vertices.clear();
        numVertices = 0;
    }

    private void setupShaderProgram() {

        // Generate VertexArrayObject
        if (Game.is32Supported()) {
            vao = new VertexArrayObject();
            vao.bind();
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("OpenGL 3.2 not supported.");
        }

        // Generate VertexBufferObject
        vbo = new VertexBufferObject();
        vbo.bind(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);

        // Create FloatBuffer
        vertices = MemoryUtil.memAllocFloat(4096);

        // Upload null data to allocate storage for the VBO
        long size = vertices.capacity() * Float.BYTES;
        vbo.uploadData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, size, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

        // Initialize variables
        numVertices = 0;
        drawing = false;

        // Load Shaders:
        Shader vertexShader, fragmentShader;
        if (Game.is32Supported()) {
            vertexShader = Shader.loadShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, "res/shaders/vshader.vert");
            fragmentShader = Shader.loadShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, "res/shaders/fshader.frag");
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("OpenGL 3.2 not supported.");
        }

        // Create ShaderProgram
        shaderProgram = new ShaderProgram();
        shaderProgram.attachShader(vertexShader);
        shaderProgram.attachShader(fragmentShader);
        if (Game.is32Supported()) {
            shaderProgram.bindFragmentDataLocation(0, "fragColor");
        }
        shaderProgram.link();
        shaderProgram.use();

        // Delete linked shaders
        vertexShader.delete();
        fragmentShader.delete();

        // Get width & height of framebuffer
        long window = GLFW.glfwGetCurrentContext();
        int width, height;
        try (MemoryStack stack = MemoryStack.stackPush()) {
            IntBuffer widthBuffer = stack.mallocInt(1);
            IntBuffer heightBuffer = stack.mallocInt(1);
            GLFW.glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, widthBuffer, heightBuffer);
            width = widthBuffer.get();
            height = heightBuffer.get();
        }

        // Specify vertex pointers
        specifyVertexAttributes();

        // Set Model Matrix to identity matrix
        Matrix4f model = new Matrix4f();
        int uniModel = shaderProgram.getUniformLocation("model");
        shaderProgram.setUniform(uniModel, model);

        // Set View Matrix to identity matrix
        Matrix4f view = new Matrix4f();
        int uniView = shaderProgram.getUniformLocation("view");
        shaderProgram.setUniform(uniView, view);

        // Set Projection Matrix to an orthographic projection
        Matrix4f projection = Matrix4f.orthographic(0f, width, 0f, height, -1f, 1f);
        int uniProjection = shaderProgram.getUniformLocation("projection");
        shaderProgram.setUniform(uniProjection, projection);

    }

    // Specifies the vertex shader pointers (attributes)
    private void specifyVertexAttributes() {

        int posAttrib = shaderProgram.getAttributeLocation("position");
        shaderProgram.enableVertexAttribute(posAttrib);
        shaderProgram.pointVertexAttribute(posAttrib, 3, 6 * Float.BYTES, 0);

        int colAttrib = shaderProgram.getAttributeLocation("color");
        shaderProgram.enableVertexAttribute(colAttrib);
        shaderProgram.pointVertexAttribute(colAttrib, 3, 6 * Float.BYTES, 3 * Float.BYTES);

    }

}
```

And here is my init() method that creates and sets up my window:

```
private void init() {


    // Setup an error callback. The default implementation
    // will print the error message in System.err.
    GLFWErrorCallback.createPrint(System.err).set();

    // Initialize GLFW. Most GLFW functions will not work before doing this.
    if ( !glfwInit() )
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to initialize GLFW");

    // Configure GLFW
    glfwDefaultWindowHints(); // optional, the current window hints are already the default
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GLFW_FALSE); // the window will stay hidden after creation
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_FALSE); // the window will be resizable

    // ONLY ON MAC OSX (?)
    //glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3); // Tell GLFW to use OpenGL verison 3.x
    //glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2); // Tell GLFW to use OpenGL version x.2 (combined -> 3.2)
    //glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    //glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GLFW_TRUE); // Should be forward compatible

    // Create the window
    window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Game_19_v0.0.1", NULL, NULL);
    if ( window == NULL )
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create the GLFW window");

    // Setup a key callback. It will be called every time a key is pressed, repeated or released.
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, (window, key, scancode, action, mods) -> {
        if ( key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_RELEASE )
            glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true); // We will detect this in the rendering loop
    });

    // Get the thread stack and push a new frame
    try ( MemoryStack stack = stackPush() ) {
        IntBuffer pWidth = stack.mallocInt(1); // int*
        IntBuffer pHeight = stack.mallocInt(1); // int*

        // Get the window size passed to glfwCreateWindow
        glfwGetWindowSize(window, pWidth, pHeight);

        // Get the resolution of the primary monitor
        GLFWVidMode vidmode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());

        // Center the window
        glfwSetWindowPos(
                window,
                (vidmode.width() - pWidth.get(0)) / 2,
                (vidmode.height() - pHeight.get(0)) / 2
        );
    } // the stack frame is popped automatically

    // Make the OpenGL context current
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    // Enable v-sync
    glfwSwapInterval(1);

    // Make the window visible
    glfwShowWindow(window);

    // This line is critical for LWJGL's interoperation with GLFW's
    // OpenGL context, or any context that is managed externally.
    // LWJGL detects the context that is current in the current thread,
    // creates the GLCapabilities instance and makes the OpenGL
    // bindings available for use.
    GL.createCapabilities();

    // Input
    glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, cursorPosCallback = new MouseInput());

    // Create renderer
    renderer = new Renderer();
    renderer.init();

    // To Render:
    buttonManager = new ButtonManager();

}
```

**EDIT 2: Temporary Solution**

I was able to use `glfwWindowHint(GLFW_DECORATED, GLFW_FALSE);` to remove the entire border from the window, title bar included, which fixed the issue. Now however, I obviously don't have the options to close, minimize, etc., on my window, although I suppose I can program those in myself if necessary. Will update if I find out any other solutions.

Comment: "*OpenGL includes the title bar in its coordinates*" OpenGL has no knowledge of the title bar. This sounds like you're misusing GLFW in some way. But we don't know what that way is, because you didn't provide a [mcve].

Comment: Ah, my bad. I thought it was something with OpenGL, not my code. Will edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GLFW functions typically work with the client area of a window (the inside window area not including titlebars, scrollbars, etc.) so `glfwSetCursorPosCallback` is giving you the expected values. If your OpenGL framebuffer is for some reason rendering things behind the title bar (whether it's an improper setup or just a platform specific detail) you should still be able to get the title bar size using [glfwGetWindowFrameSize](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html#ga1a9fd382058c53101b21cf211898f1f1):

```
IntBuffer pLeft = stack.mallocInt(1); // int*
IntBuffer pTop = stack.mallocInt(1); // int*
IntBuffer pRight = stack.mallocInt(1); // int*
IntBuffer pBottom = stack.mallocInt(1); // int*

// Get the window border sizes
glfwGetWindowFrameSize(window, pLeft, pTop, pRight, pBottom);
```

(Disclaimer: I'm just following the syntax from your code above since I'm only familiar with the C++ API.)

The size of the title bar will be stored in the `top` variable and can then be added to whatever value you get from `glfwSetCursorPosCallback` and `glfwGetWindowSize`.

```
float adjustedYpos = ypos + top;
float adjustedHeight = height + top;
float normalizedY = adjustedYpos / adjustedHeight;
float openglY = normalizedY * -2.0f - 1.0f
```

This `openglY` value should be the OpenGL [-1, 1] clip-space coordinate adjusted based on the title bar size.